# Find the standard Gibbs' free energy of formation at 298.15 K for O2 gas dissolved in the saturated aqueous solution?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, solutions, free-energy

*The solubility of $O_2(g)$ in water at $25^o \text{C}$ and $\text{1 bar}$ pressure of $O_2(g)$ above the solution is $0.00126$ $mol$ $O_2(g)/kg$ $water$.  Find $\Delta_fG_{298.15}^o(O_2(g),sln)$.*

I kinda have a clue on how to solve this, but there's just one variable I'm stuck on figuring out. I'm not sure how to get the molal-scale activity coefficient for O2 gas in solution. The answer is $\Delta_fG_{298.15}^o(O_2(g),sln) = \text{16.8 kJ/mol}$... now how would I get there?

Here's a derivation I went through to show what I have tried. The chemical potential for $O_2(g)$ relative to some reference standard state is for a real solution on the molal-scale is:

$\mu_{O_2(g)} = \mu_{m,O_2(g)}^o + RTln(\gamma_{m,O_2(g)}\frac{m_{O_2(g)}}{m^o})$

By subtracting the standard molar Gibbs energy of reactants in their elemental state, $G_{elem}^o$, and knowing that the chemical potential of a pure substance is equal to the chemical potential of that substance in a saturated solution, $\mu_{O_2(g)} = \mu_{O_2(g)}^*$, and we should get:

$\mu_{O_2(g)}^* - G_{elem}^o = \mu_{m,O_2(g)}^o - G_{elem}^o + RTln(\gamma_{m,O_2(g)}\frac{m_{O_2(g)}}{m^o})$

$\Delta_fG_T^o(O_2(g)) = \Delta_fG_T^o(O_2(g),sln) + RTln(\gamma_{m,O_2(g)}\frac{m_{O_2(g)}}{m^o})$

where $\Delta_fG_{298.15}^o(O_2(g))$ is $\text{0 kJ/mol}$ since oxygen gas is in its elemental state, and $\Delta_fG_{298.15}^o(O_2(g),sln)$ is what I am supposed to solve for. So, the final equation I think I'm supposed to use is:

> $\Delta_fG_T^o(O_2(g),sln) = -RTln(\gamma_{m,O_2(g)}\frac{m_{O_2(g)}}{m^o})$

But I don't have $\gamma_{m,O_2(g)}$... so how could I do this? This is due next Tuesday, but it would be nice to have it addressed asap.

Comment: The textbook I am using is Physical Chemistry, 6th ed., by Ira N. Levine, if that helps. This is problem 10.55a at the end of the chapter.

Comment: Isn't the chemical potential of the oxygen in the liquid solution the same as that of the oxygen in the gas phase (at equilibrium)?

Comment: Yeah, it should be; that's what I said when I wrote $\mu_{O_2(g)} = \mu_{O_2(g)}^{*}$, right?

Comment: So the free energy of formation of the oxygen in the solution should also be zero, right?

Comment: Well, no, because oxygen doesn't naturally exist in solution. It is supposed to be $\text{16.8 kJ/mol}$. However, as you would expect, the free energy of formation of the oxygen in its natural, gaseous state *is* 0 though.

Comment: I'm confused.  I thought that the chemical potential of a substance is the same in two phases that are in equilibrium.  What am I missing?

Comment: Let me clarify: O2 gas in this problem is said to be dissolved as much as possible so that it forms a saturated solution (which is why its solubility is given) at standard thermodynamic temperature and pressure. I shouldn't have assumed any particular phase equilibrium---just go off of that info when it comes to what equilibria are present.

Comment: However, the chemical potential of a substance in a saturated solution IS equal to that for the substance in its pure form---that's what I'm saying. And that's because $\mu_i = \mu_i^{*} + RTln\gamma_i\chi_i$ for the solute $i$, and at saturation, $\gamma_i = \chi_i = 1$. This would be why we treat solids in equilibrium constants to have concentrations of 1.

Comment: However, it does not mean that $\gamma_{m,i} = 1$, since $\gamma_{m,i}$ depends largely on the mol fraction of the solvent.

Comment: True or false:  For phases in thermodynamic equilibrium, the chemical potential of a given substance is the same in all phases.

Comment: I'm inclined to say that that would be true, since thermodynamic equilibrium implies mechanical, material, and thermal equilibrium, meaning no net flow in matter or energy. Chemical potential runs downhill, but if there is no net flow in energy, it should be that the chemical potential is already the same in each phase. I'm not sure if you are confused with chemical potential vs. the *change* in Gibbs energy of formation, but they're not the same thing, so $\Delta_{f}G_{T}^{o}{(O_2(g))}$ is not equal to $\Delta_{f}G_{T}^{o}{(O_2(g),sln)}$.

Comment: So the partial molar free energy of the substance in each phase is the same?

Comment: I thought I just said that? Partial molar free energy is chemical potential, at constant  temperature and pressure for a single-solute solution, if we started at $dG = -SdT + VdP + \sum_i \mu_i dn_i$. Do you know where you're going with this, or are you just asking me clarifying questions?

Comment: I'm just confused.

Comment: Okay. Well, thanks for trying. I might just end up asking my professor on Tuesday after Thanksgiving break.

Comment: I think I finally figured out what you are asking.  I forgot that the standard state for formation of a solute in solution is 1 molar.  I think you are asking why one can assume that the activity coefficient is 1.0 for the case under consideration.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if you can; it would give $\text{16.6 kJ/mol}$, but it may just be a coincidence since it isn't exact (the $\text{16.8 kJ/mol}$ came directly from the back of the book).

Comment: I really think it boils down to providing some physical justification for treating the dissolved oxygen as an ideal solution with an activity coefficient of 1.

Comment: Well... I would love to do that, but the chapter is literally all about Nonideal Solutions. :)